# Ektron Activity Stream Widget

Tags: ektron

How activity stream widget in ektron works? I have given object id as "userid" and type as "user".After saving, no ativities of that user is displaying

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you have selected is publishing events to their activity stream in their profile under workarea > settings > users > "Your User" , and then hit edit. All of the items they are pushing to the stream will be listed on one of these tabs.

I believe all the options are turned on by default, but that may vary between versions or be disabled for some other reason. Additionally, the user may simply have marked their activity as private, depending on how much control they have been granted over their own profile.

Please see the ektron reference manual for more details on configuring this widget:
http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v802/mobile_help/Advanced/Content/Managing%20User%20Communities/Activity%20Streams/Community_Management_ActivityStreams.htm#Making